# list of all SGs allowing 0.0.0.0/0 - AWS Lambda using Python

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda

I'm relatively new to lambda functions and python. Trying to accomplish a lambda function, that lists out all security groups in my AWS account, which are allowing 0.0.0.0/0. Appreciate if anyone could help

I have tried doing this, but it gives the instances, that is open to 0.0.0.0/0, instead I need a list of all SGs that has the rule

```
import sys
import boto
from boto import ec2
from boto import sns
connection=ec2.connect_to_region("region-name")
connSNS = boto.sns.connect_to_region("region-name")
sg=connection.get_all_security_groups()

listOfInstances=""
messages="Following Instances have port open to all"

def getTag(instanceId):
    reservations=connection.get_all_instances(filters={'instance_id':instanceId})
    for r in reservations:
        for i in r.instances:
            return i.tags['Name']

try:
    for securityGroup in sg:
        for rule in securityGroup.rules:
            global instanceId;
            if (rule.from_port=='0' and rule.to_port == '65535') and '0.0.0.0/0' in str(rule.grants):
                for instanceid in securityGroup.instances():
                    instanceId=str(instanceid)
                    listOfInstances += "Instance Name : " + getTag(instanceId.split(':')[1]) + "\t State:" + instanceid.state + "\t SecurityGroup:" +securityGroup.name + "\n"
                    connSNS.publish(topic='SNS-topic-arn-endpoint',message = messages + "\n" + listOfInstances, subject='ProjectName : Server List with Port Open to all')

except :
    print 'Some Error occurred : '
    print sys.exc_info()
    connSNS.publish(topic='SNS-topic-arn-endpoint',message = sys.exc_info(), subject='script ended with error')
```

Comment: Side-note: These days, you should use [`boto3`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/index.html?id=docs_gateway) rather than `boto`.

Answer (score 1):

These lines are specifically finding instances for the given security groups:

```
            for instanceid in securityGroup.instances():
                instanceId=str(instanceid)
                listOfInstances += "Instance Name : " + getTag(instanceId.split(':')[1]) + "\t State:" + instanceid.state + "\t SecurityGroup:" +securityGroup.name + "\n"
```

If you do not want the instances, then remove those lines and instead return the security groups themselves.